# Form inside another form without using MDI

Tags: vb.net

**Goal: Make Form3 (red) inside Form2 (blue) which's MDI child of Form1 (yellow)**

Form3 have it's own code and own design, I need it to be part Form2 in some situations, not always.

I could make Form3 (red) MDI child of Form2 (blue), but the problem is that Form2 (blue) ***is already MDI child*** of Form1 (yellow).

*How can I solve this problem?*

[image]

Comment: Do you use `Form3` somewhere else, or is it built just for this purpose? If that's the case, create a UserControl instead of a Form. UserControls have a Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Control has a property Controls, to which you can Add a Control, but if you try to do that with a Form, you get the exception

> Top-level control cannot be added to a control.

even though Form : Control

But you could just fill a control with a Panel with all the Form's controls in it, and take that Panel and add it to another Control.

```vb
' In Form1, Panel1 is defined, you will put the other panel in here
' In Form2, Panel1 is defined, this is the other panel
Me.Panel1.Controls.Add((New Form2).Panel1)
```

Comment: You can set the `TopMost` property of the form to False, and that will allow you to "dock" a form within another form container (e.g. a `Panel`). But if I remember right, `TopMost` has to be set in code; the property isn't exposed in the VS Properties pane. This helps avoid "megaForms", with lots of lines of code, by separating the controls and code in another Form class.

Comment: @HardCode good point, it would be cleaner to do that. I was surprised even in my solution that the event handlers defined in Form2 are still handled for its controls even when in a panel on a different form, otherwise I wouldn't have posted this. but your suggestion seems superior.